# Python| What in this string is braking new line?

Tags: python, csv, special-characters

I am using RegX to write data in a text file to CSV. I am using the following to read in the data and write it to a CSV file.

```
    with open("C:\\ProgramData\\output\\winprefetch_test_edited.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        print("defo working")
        text_raw = ("%s;" % "{;}".join([line.strip().replace("\t", ",") for line in file.readlines()]))
        text = re.sub("#.+\B \d.\d{;}", "", text_raw)


        arr_prefetch = [r.split(",") for r in [r for r in text.split("{;}")]]

        print("arr_prefetch: ", arr_prefetch)

    ###############################
    # Domain writing to csv
    fieldnames = 'Disk Name','Potential Credit Card Number', 'Source'
    with open("C:\\ProgramData\\FDA\\output\\processed\\winprefetch.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)
        writer.writerows([[diskimage_name, *row] for row in arr_prefetch])
        csvfile.close()
```

This Outputs the following

```
[![Disk Name    Potential Credit Card Number    Source  
\[windows7_pro.001\]    41693184    MPSIGSTUB.EXE   <prefetch><os>Windows Vista or Windows 7</os><filename>MPSIGSTUB.EXE</filename><header_size>240</header_size><atime>20190428T13:34:33Z</atime><runs>1</runs><filenames><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CNTDLL.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CKERNEL32.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CAPISETSCHEMA.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CKERNELBASE.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CLOCALE.NLS</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSOFTWAREDISTRIBUTION\x5CDOWNLOAD\x5CINSTALL\x5CMPSIGSTUB.EXE</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CADVAPI32.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CMSVCRT.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CSECHOST.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CRPCRT4.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CVERSION.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCRYPTBASE.DLL</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CTEMP\x5CMPSIGSTUB.LOG</file></filenames><
"
```

This is one of the line which has been throwing it off

```
<prefetch><os>Windows Vista or Windows 7</os><filename>NTOSBOOT</filename><header_size>240</header_size><atime>2019-04-28T21:05:42Z</atime><runs>2</runs><filenames><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5C$MFT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CDRIVERS\x5CCDROM.SYS</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CNTPE.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CNT5.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CNTPH.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-HYPER-V-COMMON-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-HYPER-V-COMMON-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-HYPER-V-GUEST-INTEGRATION-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-HYPER-V-GUEST-INTEGRATION-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-MEDIA-FOUNDATION-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-MEDIA-FOUNDATION-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-MEDIA-FOUNDATION-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-MEDIA-FOUNDATION-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-RESULTS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-RESULTS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-RESULTS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-ANYTIME-UPGRADE-RESULTS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BACKUP-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BACKUP-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BACKUP-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BACKUP-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BLB-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BLB-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BLB-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BLB-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ENTERPRISE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ENTERPRISE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ENTERPRISE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ENTERPRISE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEBASIC-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEBASIC-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEBASIC-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEBASIC-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEPREMIUM-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEPREMIUM-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEPREMIUM-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-HOMEPREMIUM-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-PROFESSIONAL-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-PROFESSIONAL-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-PROFESSIONAL-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-PROFESSIONAL-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-STARTER-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-STARTER-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-STARTER-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-STARTER-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ULTIMATE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ULTIMATE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ULTIMATE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BRANDING-ULTIMATE-CLIENT-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BUSINESSSCANNING-FEATURE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BUSINESSSCANNING-FEATURE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BUSINESSSCANNING-FEATURE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-BUSINESSSCANNING-FEATURE-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-FEATURES-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-FEATURES-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-FEATURES-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-FEATURES-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-LANGUAGEPACK-PACKAGE-WRAPPER~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-LANGUAGEPACK-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-LANGUAGEPACK-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-REFRESH-LANGUAGEPACK-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-WIRED-NETWORK-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-WIRED-NETWORK-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-WIRED-NETWORK-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIENT-WIRED-NETWORK-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIPSINTHELIBRARY-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIPSINTHELIBRARY-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIPSINTHELIBRARY-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CLIPSINTHELIBRARY-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CODECPACK-BASIC-ENCODER-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CODECPACK-BASIC-ENCODER-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CODECPACK-BASIC-PACKAGE-WRAPPER~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CODECPACK-BASIC-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CODECPACK-BASIC-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CODECPACK-BASIC-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-CODECPACK-BASIC-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-COMMON-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-COMMON-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~EN-US~6.1.7601.17514.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE\x5CHARDDISKVOLUME1\x5CWINDOWS\x5CSYSTEM32\x5CCATROOT\x5CF750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE\x5CMICROSOFT-WINDOWS-COMMON-DRIVERS-PACKAGE~31BF3856AD364E35~X86~~6.1.7600.16385.CAT</file><file>\x5CDEVICE
```

```
Can anyone see what character is throwing it off?
```

Comment: Please note the string is much longer but I cannot show the full string beause it is too long

Comment: I was not able to recreate the problem using that single line. Please [edit] your question to give a small sample input that recreates the problem (i.e. a handful of lines) and also show what your wanted output should be.